# Binary file I/O

Tags: io, d

How to read and write to binary files in D language? In C would be:

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/peu/Desktop/bla.bin", "wb");
    char x[4] = "RIFF";

    fwrite(x, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
```

I found rawWrite at D [docs](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html#rawWrite), but I don't know the usage, nor if does what I think. `fread` is from C:

> **T[] rawRead(T)(T[] buffer);**
>
> > If the file is not opened, throws an exception. Otherwise, calls *fread* for the file handle and throws on error.
> >
> > rawRead always read in binary mode on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rawRead and rawWrite should behave exactly like fread, fwrite, only they are templates to take care of argument sizes and lengths.

e.g.

```
 auto stream = File("filename","r+");
 auto outstring = "abcd";
 stream.rawWrite(outstring);
 stream.rewind();
 auto inbytes = new char[4];
 stream.rawRead(inbytes);
 assert(inbytes[3] == outstring[3]);
```

rawRead is implemented in terms of fread as

```
 T[] rawRead(T)(T[] buffer)
    {
        enforce(buffer.length, "rawRead must take a non-empty buffer");
        immutable result =
            .fread(buffer.ptr, T.sizeof, buffer.length, p.handle);
        errnoEnforce(!error);
        return result ? buffer[0 .. result] : null;
    }
```

Comment: What if your data is already in memory (received from an api call) instead of on disk? The Stream api doesn't support rawRead, and there's no file handle to pass to .fread ...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read in a big buffer of values (say, ints), you can simply do:

```
int[] ints = cast(int[]) std.file.read("ints.bin", numInts * int.sizeof);
```

and

```
std.file.write("ints.bin", ints);
```

Of course, if you have more structured data then Scott Wales' answer is more appropriate.