# Writing a raw binary structure to file in D?

Tags: struct, d

I'm trying to have a binary file which contains several binary records defined in some `struct`. However, I do cannot seem to find how to do it. Looking at other examples, I've managed to write `string`s without problems, but not `struct`. I just want to write it like I would in `C` with `fwrite(3)`, but in `D` version 2.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- using `stream.write(tr)` - writes human readable/debug representation
- using `stream.rawWrite(tr)` - this sounded like what I need, but fails to compile with:

> Error: template std.stdio.File.rawWrite cannot deduce function from
> argument types !()(TitleRecord), candidates are:
>
> /usr/lib/ldc/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/d/std/stdio.d(1132):        std.stdio.File.rawWrite(T)(in T[] buffer)

- trying `rawWrite` as above, but casting data to various things, also never compiles.
- even trying to get back to `C` with `fwrite`, but can't get deep enough to get file descriptor I need.

Reading [the docs](https://dlang.org/library/std/stdio/file.raw_write.html) has not been very helpful (writing strings works for me too, but not writing `struct`). I'm sure there must be simple way to do it, but I'm not able to find it.... Other SO questions [did not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860554/2600099) [help me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8706466/2600099). I `D 1.0`, it might have been accomplished with `stream.writeExact(&tr, tr.sizeof)` but that is no longer an option.

```
import std.stdio;

struct TitleRecord {
        short id;
        char[49] text;
};

TitleRecord tr;

void main()
{
 auto stream = File("filename.dat","wb+");
 tr.id = 1234;
 tr.text = "hello world";
 writeln(tr);
 //stream.write(tr);
 //stream.rawWrite(tr);
 //stream.rawWrite(cast(ubyte[52]) tr);
 //stream.rawWrite(cast(ubyte[]) tr);
 //fwrite(&tr, 4, 1, stream);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this that error is saying it expects an array not a struct. So one easy way to do it is to simply slice a pointer and give that to rawWrite:

```
stream.rawWrite((&tr)[0 .. 1]);
```

The `(&tr)` gets the address, thus converting your struct to a pointer. Then the `[0 .. 1]` means get a slice of it from the beginning, grabbing just one element.

Thus you now have a `T[]` that rawWrite can handle containing your one element.

Be warned if you use the `@safe` annotation this will not pass, you'd have to mark it `@trusted`. Also of course any references inside your struct (including `string`) will be written as binary pointers instead of data as you surely know from C experience. But in the case you showed there you're fine.

edit: BTW you could also just use `fwrite` if you like, copy/pasting the same code over from C  (except it is `foo.sizeof` instead of `sizeof foo`). The D `File` thing is just a small wrapper around C's `FILE*` and you can get the original FILE* back out to pass to the other functions with `stream.getFP()` http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.stdio.File.getFP.html )

Answer (score 1):

`rawWrite` expects an array, but there are many workarounds.

One is to create a single element array.

```
file.rawWrite([myStruct]);
```

Another one is casting the struct into an array. My library called bitleveld has a function for that called `reinterpretAsArray`. This also makes it easy to create checksums of said structs.

Once in a while I've encountered issues with alignment using this method, so be careful. Could be fixed by changing the `align` property of the struct.